# Postgres sql jsonb_set() is not working fine

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to update jsonb value. Please tell me what I did wrong.
Here I have a table that has a profile column with jsonb datatype.

```
UPDATE <TABLE NAME> SET
"profile" = jsonb_set('{"lastName": "dada"}'::jsonb, '{lastName}'::text[] , concat('"', (profile->'lastName'), '"')::jsonb, false)
where email = 'abc@example.com'
```

> ERROR: function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], jsonb, boolean) does not exist LINE 2: "profile" = jsonb_set('{"lastName": "dada"}'::jsonb, '{lastN... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. SQL state: 42883 Character: 44

Comment: What is your Postgres version? `select version();` will tell you

Comment: My current version of pgAdmin is 4.13 and postgresSql is 9.4.4.

Comment: `jsonb_set` was introduced in Postgres 9.5, it's not available in 9.4 - but 9.4 will be [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) very soon, so you should plan an upgrade anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is a correction:

```
UPDATE <TABLE NAME> SET
profile = jsonb_set('{"lastName": "dada"}'::jsonb, '{lastName}'::text[] , 
                      (profile->'lastName')::jsonb, false)
where email = 'abc@example.com'
```

The error was here: `concat('"', (profile->'lastName'), '"')::jsonb`

Mind you though, this just sets the lastname field back to the sam lastname value :-)

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: function jsonb_set(jsonb, text[], jsonb, boolean) does not exist. I am still getting this error.